# Как получить значение из массива?

Tags: python-3.x

Пишу:

```
vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})
```

Получаю ответ от вк следующий ответ:

> {'count': 1, 'items': [{'conversation': {'peer': {'id': 242369682, 'type': 'user', 'local_id': ТутНомерID}, 'in_read': 185, 'out_read': 186, 'last_message_id': 186, 'unread_count': 1, 'unanswered': True, 'can_write': {'allowed': True}}, 'last_message': {'date': 1556627567, 'from_id': ТутНомерID, 'id': 186, 'out': 0, 'peer_id': ТутНомерID, 'text': 'донат', 'conversation_message_id': 176, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'random_id': 0, 'attachments': [], 'is_hidden': False}}], 'unread_count': 1}

Как мне вытащить от туда нужные значения? Тот же ID например.
Я имею ввиду не конкретно значение ID через API вконтакта, а вообще метод получения значения из такого массива.
Т.е. будь это простым массивом, было бы ясно, что там можно написать массив[номерАргумента].
Тут же как-то сложнее.

Comment: import json и сам получаемый ответ  json.loads(answer) - и это станет из json'a словарем

Comment: А что выводит `print(type(vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})))`? Я думаю, у вас там будет `dict` или `str`. Скорее всего, `dict`. От вашего ответа уже можно дальше плясать :)

Comment: Это не массив..

Comment: @Taarim Разве json не является словарем изначально?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
import json
response = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"}).text
response_json = json.loads(response)
```

А далее можно работать с `response_json` как с dict.

Answer (score -2):

попробуйте использовать  `Json.parse()` и  `json.strigify()`.

Comment: а разве в питоне так можно?

Comment: у меня получилось

Comment: @АнуарТемирбулат, на js получился, на питоне через стандартный модуль json -- нет